# Url builder/utility for android

Tags: android, url

Please help to find a lib which can provide url parsing/building functionality which can be used with Android platform. Character escaping is desired.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

How about Uri.Builder?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html